# how to fix this TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/PYTHON projects/chrome automation/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.chrome()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

I installed selenium and webdriver but this keeps happening. whats the problem?

Answer (score 1):

The way to read this error is `webdriver` module does not have an object called "chrome()". It does have one called "Chrome()", so try this?

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Also a good IDE will help you spot such issues quicker. Plenty of free ones out there.

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Python is case sensitive.

https://chromedriver.chromium.org/getting-started

use:

```py
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver')
```